# Why do these two segments of code give me different results?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have an object `G` which is a graph.  I overloaded the bracket operators so that `G[i]` returns a `list<int>` (STL list) which is a list of vertex `i`'s adjacencies.

I have these two segments of code which are both supposed to iterate over `G[i]`, but only the first one works.

```
list<int> adj = G[2];

for(list<int>::iterator it = adj.begin(); it != adj.end(); it++) {
    cout << *it << " ";
}
```

This does not work...

```
for(list<int>::iterator it = G[2].begin(); it != G[2].end(); it++) {
    cout << *it << " ";
}
```

As far as I can see, they do the same thing.  Can anyone explain why the second code segment does not work?  Also, is there a better way of iterating over my list?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: It doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I overloaded the bracket operators so that `G[i]` returns a `list<int>`

Make sure that the return type of your `operator []` is `list<int>&`, not `list<int>`. Otherwise, a copy will be created upon return each time you call `G[2]`, so `G[2].end()` will never be reached.

If you invoke `[]` once, the way you do in the first code fragment featuring `adj`, the problem will not be visible (although a list will be copied two times - once in the `return`, and once more in the assignment operator). The second fragment exposes the problem by calling the `[]` operator multiple times.

Comment: This was the reason!  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `Graph::opertor[]` returns a new `list` everytime, so you can't compare iterator between different lists.

```
list<int> adj = G[2];
list<int>::iterator end = adj.end();

for(list<int>::iterator it = adj.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
  cout << *it << " ";
}
```